# Using cfs:http-publish

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use the **cfs:http-publish** package at https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-publish. While I've got the `GET - /api/list` functionality working, I don't know how to obtain a single document:

```
(GET - /api/list/:id - find one published document).
```

Can someone provide a curl example of this, assuming a certain collection of objections.
eg: `{a:3, b:2}`, `{a:4, b:3}`, and requiring to obtain the object with `{a:3}`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in the query function.

```
HTTP.publish({collection: myList},function( ){
  return myList.find(this.query);
});
```

this.query contains the data you sent with your request.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/myList?a=3
```

I don't know enough about mongo to know if this is a potential security risk, if anyone can comment on that please do.